# Accessing instances of a class from qml context

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am new both QT and QML.  I have a class, which instantiates subclasses.  I would like to expose the methods within these subclasses to my UI with some qml binding.

For example

```
class MainClass: QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
   Subclass subclass;
   MainClass();

}

class Subclass:QObject
{
  Q_Object
  Subclass();

  public slots:
  void someMethod();
}
```

Main.C

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView; 
    MainClass mainclass;      
    view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("MainClass", &mainClass);
    view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view->show();
}
```

In this case I would like to access mainclass.subclass.someMethod() from within the QML UI.

Is there a good way to do this? Should I provide wrapper methods in MainClass for each function/property I would like to access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible by making `SubClass` a property of `MainClass`. For example:

```
class MainClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(SubClass *subClass MEMBER subClass CONSTANT)

public:
    MainClass();

private:
    SubClass *subclass;
};
```

These are called "[grouped properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#grouped-properties)" in QML.